# Hibernate jpa oneToMany: how to add to "one" list of many children

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can you help me with some issue? I have two entities Project and Page connected by 'one to many':

Project model (also connected with User model)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private User user;

@Column(name="projectName", unique = true, nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private String projectName;

@Column(name="style")
@JsonProperty
private String style;

@Column(name="menu")
@JsonProperty
private String menu;

@JsonProperty
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "project", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Page> pages;
//getters and setters
```

Page model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty
private Integer id;

@Column(name="content")
@JsonProperty
private String content;

@Column(name="pageName", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty
private String pageName;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "projectName", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private Project project;
//getters and setters
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void updatePages(Set<Page> pages, Integer projectId) {
    Project project = entityManager.find(Project.class, projectId);
    project.setPages(pages);
}
```

But have Hibernate queries without rezult and errors.

```
Hibernate: 
select
    project0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    project0_.menu as menu2_1_0_,
    project0_.projectName as projectN3_1_0_,
    project0_.style as style4_1_0_,
    project0_.username as username5_1_0_,
    user1_.id as id1_4_1_,
    user1_.email as email2_4_1_,
    user1_.enabled as enabled3_4_1_,
    user1_.password as password4_4_1_,
    user1_.username as username5_4_1_,
    userroles2_.username as username3_4_2_,
    userroles2_.id as id1_2_2_,
    userroles2_.id as id1_2_3_,
    userroles2_.role as role2_2_3_,
    userroles2_.username as username3_2_3_ 
from
    projects project0_ 
inner join
    users user1_ 
        on project0_.username=user1_.username 
left outer join
    roles userroles2_ 
        on user1_.username=userroles2_.username 
where
    project0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
/* load project.model.User */ select
    user0_.id as id1_4_2_,
    user0_.email as email2_4_2_,
    user0_.enabled as enabled3_4_2_,
    user0_.password as password4_4_2_,
    user0_.username as username5_4_2_,
    projects1_.username as username5_4_4_,
    projects1_.id as id1_1_4_,
    projects1_.id as id1_1_0_,
    projects1_.menu as menu2_1_0_,
    projects1_.projectName as projectN3_1_0_,
    projects1_.style as style4_1_0_,
    projects1_.username as username5_1_0_,
    userroles2_.username as username3_4_5_,
    userroles2_.id as id1_2_5_,
    userroles2_.id as id1_2_1_,
    userroles2_.role as role2_2_1_,
    userroles2_.username as username3_2_1_ 
from
    users user0_ 
left outer join
    projects projects1_ 
        on user0_.username=projects1_.username 
left outer join
    roles userroles2_ 
        on user0_.username=userroles2_.username 
where
    user0_.username=?
Hibernate: 
select
    pages0_.project as project4_1_0_,
    pages0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    pages0_.id as id1_0_1_,
    pages0_.content as content2_0_1_,
    pages0_.pageName as pageName3_0_1_,
    pages0_.project as project4_0_1_ 
from
    pages pages0_ 
where
    pages0_.project=?
```

I want to update pages in project. What is the best way to do it?

**UPD**

```
Project project = entityManager.find(Project.class, projectId);
    entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Page p WHERE p.project = :project")
            .setParameter("project",project)
            .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner side of the association Project-Pages is on `Page` entity, in hibernate (because the way it resolves bi-directional one-to-many) it means that you must set the `Page.project` for every `Page` that you want to link with the `Project`. It won't work if you only add the Pages to the Project's collection of pages.

Do this,

```
@Override
public void updatePages(Set<Page> pages, Integer projectId) {
  Project project = entityManager.find(Project.class, projectId);
  for (Page p: pages) {
    p.setProject (project);
    //the pages are new? then also do em.persist(p) 
  }
 }
```

The select statement you see right now, according your entity model, are needed to retrieve the project and generated when you invoke the `entityManager.find` method.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But my Set<Page> pages doesn't in the database yet. It comes from client side. In this case, it will work?

Comment: I suppose that, so I edit the answer, see the comment in code :)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! You really saved me:)

Comment: Can you help me again?:) What is the easiest way to delete all childs (pages) in project?

Comment: Delete along with the Project? add CascadeType.REMOVE to project.pages collection.

Comment: No, delete without project. Select all pages of project and delete them

Comment: Depends on the JPA and Hibernate version but the easiest way knowing the project's id is using bulk delete query, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk_ops

Comment: I tried to delete childs with code, updated in topic. Can you check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84951/discussion-between-jahra-and-guillermo).